# For loop inside a function PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, math, return

A total noob needs to do a math calculation in a for loop inside a function.
The closest I come is this, but it does not work of course.

```
    function z1()
{
  for ($x=1; $x<=11; $x++)
  {
    $z1=2/3+5*$x/(3-$x);
  }
  return $z1;
}
```

Any help or a solution would be appreciated

EDIT: FIXED
Needed to declare what to do if it is NaN or infinite

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the expected result?

Comment: It should return $z1 but it returns nothing to me. I am not sure about the structure, is it all right?

Comment: The structure is fine and it works for me (albeit with a divide by zero error).

Comment: Do you actually call/execute the function?

Comment: Yes, I execute it but I get division by zero error

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I'll make some assumptions.

In addition to a divide by zero error this gets, you are overwriting the value of $z1 each time the loop executes, so the value of $z1 once you return is whatever the final iteration of the loop assigned to $z1.

I think you may want to initialize the variable before the loop and use the += operator inside the loop, so the value of $z1 is incremented each time the loop iterates.

```
function z1() {
    $z1 = 0;

    for ($x = 1; $x <= 11; $x++) {
        $z1 += 2 / 3 + 5 * $x / (3 - $x);
    }
    return $z1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I get division by zero

Comment: Yes that's a problem with your math logic. For one, when $x becomes 3 the last part [$x / (3 - $x)] will be trying to divide by 0; you need to rework it a bit.

Comment: That is not my math logic it was a homework task. Thanks once again anyway

Comment: You stated in your question it was your code and my phrasing was based on that. Next time I recommend providing more context and/or explanation so you elicit better answers.